# Joomla! How To Use JInputJson

Tags: php, json, joomla3.0

I have an ajax that send data as a json string

```
{"Series":"M","Model":"MAE","Steel":"No","Floor":"","Wood":""}
```

in my controller, I am expected to parse the string so that it will be available as a Jinput

```
public function getData()
{
    $this->setAjaxRequestParams();

    $params = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    echo new JResponseJson($params);
}
```

However when I return the response to the browser it shows as `null`

Can anyone show me how to use `JInputJSON`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$jinput = $app->input->json;
$series = $jinput->get('Series');
```